# How do I read and show a users Twitter feed?

Tags: javascript, html, json, twitter

This might be a big question, but I find the Twitter developer website even more confusing than the Facebook developers site. So after finishing the Facebook API, I'd like to do some more research and find out how the Twitter API works.

What I want to do is make a basic application that could read and display a logged in users Twitter home feed, and publish a Tweet to their profile. But first things first, how do I read and show a users feed? 
First off I'll have to authenticate a user and my application. Could anyone show me an example on that with code that I could read up on? 
Then I'll have to read that users feed. This is done by sending a GET request to /statuses/user_timeline.json, but how do I do this in code? How do I receive the response, and lastly how can I display that to a user?

I know Facebook had an example on their webpage which walked you through step by step a process like this (with code), but do Twitter have anything like that? If not, could anyone who has a clue give me a little guide and some code?

Now, if you know/ have the time to respond further, I would like to know how I can publish something to a users stream. I assume it's done by sending a POST request to something, but I haven't read up on that yet. If you know, please feel free to add it to your answer. If not, no stress. Reading the stream is the most important.

So, thanks for taking the time to read through this and hopefully someone knows how to do this/ where to read up on this. Thanks in advance.

- Aleksander

Answer (score 0):

I use PHP to get a users tweets. I'm presuming it could be done with JS too.

Here is what I use:

```
function getTweets($userid,$x){
    $url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/$userid.xml?count=$x";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die('Could not get tweets');
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($xml->status as $status){
      echo grabTweetData($status);
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

function grabTweetData($status) {
    $id = $status->id;
    $user = $status->screen_name;
    $text = twitterify( $status->text );
    $timestamp = $status->created_at;
    $date = substr($timestamp, 0, 10).', '.substr($timestamp, -4).' at '.substr($timestamp, 11, 5);

    $tweet = '<a href="https://twitter.com/'.$user.'/status/'.$id.'"><li>';
    $tweet .= '<div class="ttext">'.utf8_decode($text).'</div>';
    $tweet .= '<div class="tdate">Posted on: '.$date.'</div>';
    $tweet .= '</li></a>';
    return $tweet;
}

function twitterify($ret) {
    //links #tags and @users
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" >\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" >\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" >@\\1</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=\\1&src=hash\" >#\\1</a>", $ret);
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: This code is using Twitter API 1.0, which is already deprecated. It **WILL BREAK** in the next few months. Also, it can't be used via Javascript, as there's no way to load content from `api.twitter.com` without being under the same origin.

Comment: @duskwuff Yeah I really need to update this code... I thought that may have been the case though could use ajax to load it in with PHP. Doesn't 1.1 use json instead of xml?

Comment: The bigger issue you're going to run into is that 1.1 requires OAuth login for all operations, even if you're just trying to access public data.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. I see people are saying it's 1.0, and I really want to use 1.1... So, could I ask where you found the guide to write this code? Is there a guide that Twitter has on writing your first Twitter app or something? Like I said, Facebook has one, but it took me forever to find it. I actually needed help from someone here at StackOverflow to find it. Do you know if Twitter has one of the same?

Comment: Well I pretty much wrote the code myself. Just got the twitterify function from somewhere (I forget where). Have a look into grabbing a json file and reading data from it. You will need to get the file shown here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting started with APIs you should check out [Temboo](http://temboo.com). Temboo makes APIs easier to work with by letting you experiment with thousands of API calls in your browser, and then generating source code for the API calls you want in the language of your choice (Java, iOS, Android, PHP, Ruby, Python, Node.js). You can also generate curl requests to the Temboo API if you're using Javascript.

Temboo's Twitter support, which will help you do everything you mentioned above, is here: https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Twitter

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo).